# Drawing an arrow over a tabular with tikzmark

Tags: tikzmark

I'm trying to get lines to trace diagonally along the entries in a tabular using tikz and tikzmark but tikz isn't drawing on top of the text in the tabular. How can I fix this? I would like to keep using an appropriate mathy structure like tabular, not change to something pgf-specific, just draw a line on top, like the one that's used to prove countability of the rationals like here: https://plus.maths.org/issue47/features/macgregor/diagram3.gif but preferrably with an arrow head at the end. What's a good way to do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
$(1,1)$ & $(1,2)$ & $(1,3)$ & $(1,4)$ & $(1,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$(2,1)$ & $(2,2)$ & $(2,3)$ & $(2,4)$ & $(2,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$(3,1)$ & $(3,2)$ & $(3,3)$ & $(3,4)$ & $(3,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$(4,1)$ & $(4,2)$ & $(4,3)$ & $(4,4)$ & $(4,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$(5,1)$ & $(5,2)$ & $(5,3)$ & $(5,4)$ & $(5,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ \\
\end{tabular}

\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {#2};
}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\tikzmark{1-1}{$(1,1)$} & \tikzmark{1-2}{$(1,2)$} & \tikzmark{1-3}{$(1,3)$} & \tikzmark{1-4}{$(1,4)$} & \tikzmark{1-5}{$(1,5)$} & $\cdots$ \\
\tikzmark{2-1}{$(2,1)$} & $(2,2)$ & $(2,3)$ & $(2,4)$ & $(2,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
\tikzmark{3-1}{$(3,1)$} & $(3,2)$ & $(3,3)$ & $(3,4)$ & $(3,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
\tikzmark{4-1}{$(4,1)$} & $(4,2)$ & $(4,3)$ & $(4,4)$ & $(4,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
\tikzmark{5-1}{$(5,1)$} & $(5,2)$ & $(5,3)$ & $(5,4)$ & $(5,5)$ & $\cdots$ \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ \\
\end{tabular}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [->,overlay,remember picture,xshift=20ex] (1-1) -- (2-1) -- (1-2) -- (1-3) -- (3-1) -- (4-1) -- (1-4) -- (1-5);

\end{document}
```

Comment: I note that you're using quite an old version of `\tikzmark`.  It's been considerably updated and upgraded and is now provided by the `tikzmark` library.  What you're using here is closest to the `\tikzmarknode` from that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want some math environment I would recommend `array` or `matrix` (from `amsmath`). The line can be drawn as a plot between the coordinates. I also did a slight change in `\tikzmark` command to get a better overview when writing the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture] \node (#1-#2) {$(#1,#2)$};}
%%
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{matrix}
    \tikzmark{1}{1} & \tikzmark{1}{2} & \tikzmark{1}{3} & \tikzmark{1}{4} & \tikzmark{1}{5} & \cdots\\
    \tikzmark{2}{1} & \tikzmark{2}{2} & \tikzmark{2}{3} & \tikzmark{2}{4} & \tikzmark{2}{5} & \cdots\\
    \tikzmark{3}{1} & \tikzmark{3}{2} & \tikzmark{3}{3} & \tikzmark{3}{4} & \tikzmark{3}{5} & \cdots\\
    \tikzmark{4}{1} & \tikzmark{4}{2} & \tikzmark{4}{3} & \tikzmark{4}{4} & \tikzmark{4}{5} & \cdots\\
    \tikzmark{5}{1} & \tikzmark{5}{2} & \tikzmark{5}{3} & \tikzmark{5}{4} & \tikzmark{5}{5} & \cdots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
  \end{matrix}
\end{displaymath}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[->] plot coordinates {(1-1) (2-1) (1-2) (1-3) (3-1) (4-1) (1-4) (1-5) (5-1)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a minor comment on `\tikzmark`: I would use `\tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` library, and then define a wrapper around that.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, the lines just connect your nodes (x,y). To connect the lines, you have to draw them center to center:

```
\draw [->,overlay,remember picture,xshift=20ex] (1-1.center) -- (2-1.center) -- (1-2.center) -- (1-3.center) -- (3-1.center) -- (4-1.center) -- (1-4.center) -- (1-5.center);
```

The result would be:[image]

It's not that nice aligned. If you don't have a specific reason to use tabular, i would recommend array here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {#2};}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*6{c}}
(1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) & (1,4) & (1,5) & \cdots \\
(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) & (2,4) & (2,5) & \cdots \\
(3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) & (3,4) & (3,5) & \cdots \\
(4,1) & (4,2) & (4,3) & (4,4) & (4,5) & \cdots \\
(5,1) & (5,2) & (5,3) & (5,4) & (5,5) & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
\]


\[
\begin{array}{*6{c}}
\tikzmark{1-1}{(1,1)} & \tikzmark{1-2}{(1,2)} & \tikzmark{1-3}{(1,3)} & \tikzmark{1-4}{(1,4)} & \tikzmark{1-5}{(1,5)} & \cdots \\
\tikzmark{2-1}{(2,1)} & \tikzmark{2-2}{(2,2)} & \tikzmark{2-3}{(2,3)} & (2,4) & (2,5) & \cdots \\
\tikzmark{3-1}{(3,1)} & \tikzmark{3-2}{(3,2)} & (3,3) & (3,4) & (3,5) & \cdots \\
\tikzmark{4-1}{(4,1)} & (4,2) & (4,3) & (4,4) & (4,5) & \cdots \\
\tikzmark{5-1}{(5,1)} & (5,2) & (5,3) & (5,4) & (5,5) & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}
\]

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->,overlay,remember picture] (1-1.center) -- (2-1.center) -- (1-2.center) -- (1-3.center) -- (2-2.center) -- (3-1.center) -- (4-1.center) -- (3-2.center) -- (2-3.center) -- (1-4.center) -- (1-5.center);

\end{document}
```

The result is much nicer:
[image]

Sadly it does not solve the problem of the unequally spaced entries completly. I Think that has something todo with making some entries nodes while some are not, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: \tikzmark inserts it's argument in text mode so you should switch to math mode again: `\tikzmark{1-1}{$(1,1)$}` etc.

Comment: Oh thanks! i didn't knew that! The lines are aligned now, but there is still the unequal spacing between the columns...

Comment: The misalignment is probably caused by the `overlay` in `\tikzmark`. It essentially means the node should take no space, and therefore the first column is more narrow.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the other answer because of the alignment issues, but this one helped me understand some things, like I didn't know about .center.

Comment: `\tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` package is math-aware: if used in a math environment then it will internally switch to the appropriate math mode.  I'd recommend using the appropriate command from that library to make use of improvements like this.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical `{array}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and colummns. It's possible to use these nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
(1,1)  & (1,2)  & (1,3)  & (1,4)  & (1,5)  & \dots  \\
(2,1)  & (2,2)  & (2,3)  & (2,4)  & (2,5)  & \dots  \\
(3,1)  & (3,2)  & (3,3)  & (3,4)  & (3,5)  & \dots  \\
(4,1)  & (4,2)  & (4,3)  & (4,4)  & (4,5)  & \dots  \\
(5,1)  & (5,2)  & (5,3)  & (5,4)  & (5,5)  & \dots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [->]
                 (1-1.center) 
              -- (2-1.center) 
              -- (1-2.center) 
              -- (1-3.center) 
              -- (3-1.center) 
              -- (4-1.center) 
              -- (1-4.center) 
              -- (1-5.center) 
              -- (5-1.center) ;
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

The alignment issue pointed out by [SeverinBang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319023/96422) is due to the `overlay` option for horizontal alignment, and the node anchor for vertical alignment.

You can see the effect of `overlay` in the original code of the question by drawing the box created by `tikzmark` command with `fbox`:

```
\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {#2};}
}
```

[image]

The cells with `tikzmark` have zero width and zero height, and that null box is what is aligned with cells with normal text. If the `overlay` option is removed:

```
\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\tikz[remember picture] \node (#1) {#2};}
}
```

[image]

Now `tikz` command creates a box that is taken into account by the `tabular` environment. The horizontal alignment is not perfect because the definition of `tikzmark` command includes a carriage return at the end which is equivalent to a space (you can remove it with a `%`). In addition, the box created by `node` has a margin of 0.33em with respect the contents of the node by default. This distance can be modified by `inner sep` option:

```
\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}{\tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}%
}
```

[image]

The vertical alignment depends on the alignment of the box created by tikz with the baseline of surrounding text. Without any special options, the box created by tikz is positioned just over the baseline of the surrounding text (it has a zero depth).

[image]

You can change that with the `baseline` option, that defines at which point in the tikz picture will be anchored the baseline:

```
\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}%
}
```

[image]

Finally, if the line must connect the node centers, you can use the solution proposed by [StefanH](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319035/96422), or define two nodes on `tikzmark` command: one for reference, and one for the text,

```
\newcommand {\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture, baseline=(A.base)] \draw coordinate (#1) node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {#2};%
}
```

[image]